# Unity doesn't Respond when clicked play button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash

Unity stoped Responding when clicked play button.
[image: as u can see in image]

Problem occurred from nowhere.

Scripts Doesn't Contain Any loops.

help pls, thanks.
ps. (using mac mini m1, unity version:2020.3.39f1).

I have Tried to restart unity and mac, but no results.

Comment: You need to show the onclick code. Chances an infinite loop

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There. I have solved this problem.
Problem was on a script with a loop going infinite.
(how to find that script?), we must first find game object that the script is in. simply set active all your game object false then in play mode set them active true one by one and then when your unity stops responding that's our problem.
find in script while and solve code.

Comment: So apparently `Problem occurred from nowhere. Scripts Doesn't Contain Any loops.` is just wrong then as was commented ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).